# openshift: I just opened an account in openshift using my github, but which is my password, my github password didn't work

Tags: openshift

My git hub password didn't work, which is my password. I just opened my open-shift account and i assumed that my password was the same of git hub. but when i tried to install rhc using rhc set up it showed me a message "incorrect account or password"

Comment: rhc is not loger suportt instead use oc, download here https://console.preview.openshift.com/console/command-line

Comment: And to save you some trouble in understanding what documentation to follow, use instead the free eBook on latest OpenShift version. https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html It uses a all-in-one VM, but can still apply to online as well. If you see ``rhc`` or cartridges, that is the old OpenShift version, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When logging in, please make sure that you are selecting "(Next Gen) Web Console", as the "OpenShift Web Console" is for OpenShift v2.

[image: Login screenshot]